# Rebind indirect depdendency with ninject childkernel

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

I am using Ninject and Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel

I have the following interfaces `IService` and `IServiceProvider`

My `IServiceProvider` implementation takes an `IService` instance

```
public interface IServiceProvider
{
    IService Service { get; }
}
public class ServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    public ServiceProvider(IService service)
    {
        this.Service = service;
    }
    public IService Service { get; private set; }
}
```

Now I do the following

```
var container = new StandardKernel();
container.Bind<IService>().To<Service>();
container.Bind<IServiceProvider>.To<ServiceProvider>();

// later in code
var child = new ChildKernel(container);
child.Bind<IService>().To<ChildService>();

var provider = child.Get<IServiceProvider>();
var serviceA = provider.Service;      // <-- Service
var serviceB = child.Get<IService>(); // <-- ChildService
```

As you can see `child.Get<IService>()` works as expected and returns ChildService but I also want every instance of IServiceProvider contructed with the child kernel to use ChildService. Is this possible with `Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel`

Please note: I already posted this on the `Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel` [issue tracker](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel/issues/9) but I am not even sure if this is an issue or I am just using it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's not supported.

This is how the child kernel works (to my knowledge TM):
If you ask for a type from the child kernel, it first checks it's own bindings to see whether it can satisfy it. If it can, it will return the value (constructing an instance and dependencies if necessary). If the child kernel doesn't have a binding which satisfies the request, it will ask the parent kernel to resolve it and return the result of the parent kernel.

- Your child kernel doesn't have a binding for `IServiceProvider`
- The request is thus forwarded to the parent kernel for resolution
- The parent kernel does have a binding for `IService`, it constructs it based on the bindings the parent kernel knows - the parent kernel does not know about the child kernel and the child kernel's bindings. It doesn't even know the request came from a child kernel.
- the child kernel returns `IServiceProvider` and `IService` - both resolved from the parent kernel.

Long story short: If you want the child kernel to resolve the `IServiceProvider` you need to add a binding for `IServiceProvider` to the child kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. In the real world I am using `Nancy` with `Nancy.BootStrappers.Ninject` which use a child kernel per request and I can't rebind `IServiceProvider` the interface that I rebind may or may not be used as an indirect dependency. Are there any other ways to workaround this?

Comment: i've double-checked and as long as you cannot add bindings to the child kernel i don't see a way to workaround this. In the first place, one should rather use scopes (for example NamedScope) than Childkernels with Ninject... that's probably why there's no perfect ChildKernel support, anyway.